# HTTP status for "email not verified"

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I have seen the list of all HTTP status codes.
However to me it looks like there is no code for "email not verified" (used for authentication/authorization). 
Did you ever had the same "problem"? What HTTP status code did you use?

I guess it should be a code starting with a 4 as it's a "client error".

Comment: Not sure this needs a separate status code. It could be answered with a 401 or 403 and the exact reason explained in the body

Comment: Give 404. Not verified = Not Found
or Give 200 and display the msg that your email is not verified

Comment: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Comment: It's always good to remember that status codes are just a tool for implementing behavior and describing http responses. If you treat a status code a certain way it's because you want certain behavior in certain circumstances. Choosing one that is semantically correct makes it easier for other devs to understand, but ultimately the user will never know. Do what's easiest

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `4xx` class of status code is intended for situations in which the client seems to have erred:

> [**6.5. Client Error 4xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)
>
> The `4xx` (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
> seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

For *authentication* and *authorization*, `401` and `403` are the proper status codes to be used, respectively. Regardless of the status code, you should always describe that reason of the error in the response payload.

### `401` Unauthorized

Use this status code for problems with HTTP *authentication*, that is, invalid credentials.

> [**3.1. 401 Unauthorized**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)
>
> The `401` (Unauthorized) status code **indicates that the request has not
> been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for
> the target resource**. The server generating a `401` response MUST send
> a `WWW-Authenticate` header field containing at least one
> challenge applicable to the target resource.
>
> **If the request included authentication credentials, then the `401`
> response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
> credentials**.  The user agent MAY repeat the request with a new or
> replaced `Authorization` header field.  If the `401`
> response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the
> user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then
> the user agent SHOULD present the enclosed representation to the
> user, since it usually contains relevant diagnostic information.

### `403` Forbidden

Use this status code for problems with *authorization*, that is, the credentials are valid but they are insufficient to grant access.

> [**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
>
> The `403` (Forbidden) status code **indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it**. A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> **If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the
> server considers them insufficient to grant access**. The client
> SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same
> credentials. The client MAY repeat the request with new or different
> credentials. However, a request might be forbidden for reasons
> unrelated to the credentials. [...]

Answer (score 3):

While CodeCaster has provided a very definitive answer as a comment, that which is correct is *sometimes* not appropriate.

Firstly, you'll see there is **no mention** of email addresses in the specs. Similarly there is no mention of shoe sizes, model railway gauges, breeds of dogs nor many other things. It is not relevant to HTTP. This is just a data item.

You seem to have some state associated with this data item which you use for authentication purposes - but don't provide any explanation of that state nor how it is applied. I assume that you mean that the "not verified" state means that the only association between the data item and the user interacting with your site is an assertion of the user. And further that you do not allow the user to authenticate with this as a token.

It may seem I'm being pedantic here - but there are other, valid interpretations of "email not verified". You should have provided more information in your question.

There's another gap in your story: which request are we taking about here? Again, I'll take the liberty of assuming that the request is an attempt to authenticate.

In this case, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the request. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with the client. There is nothing intrinsically wrong at the server. Not permitting the user to authenticate is a policy decision based on the data.

Another critical bit of information missing from your question is what is actually making the request. If its a form sent by a browser, then returning anything other than a 200 OK (or 204, or a redirect to a 200) to MSIE will, by default, cause the browser to display an internal message and *not the content you send*.

OTOH if the client is an application running on the users device, or an Ajax request, then you control the API and can define your own semantics. If you want to return a 692 status code to represent this condition, then you can return a 692 error code. You can even inject your own headers in the response (by convention these should begin with 'X-').

In the defined state the authentication fails. But returning a 401 response will prompt a browser to attempt HTTP authentication - which doesn't address the issue.

IMHO, the nearest existing code is 403 or [422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2). But based on the information you've supplied I can't say if thats what you *should* be using.

Comment: "by convention these should begin with 'X-'." This has been a best practice back in MIME-days and has never been standard. In fact, RFCs 7230ff are [actively discouraging](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-8.3.1) from this practice. Oh, and inventing new status codes residing in completely non-standard code ranges has never been a good idea. A 4xx-code should really be issued here.

Comment: Or maybe 423 as it means the resource is locked.